# Default umask for cron jobs

Tags: cron, shell, umask

How to set default umask for cron jobs, please? (On RHEL 6.)

Jobs are started under non-interactive (obviously) no-login (?) shell. Not only I [prefer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) dash over bash. But consider also bash called as `/bin/sh`. It seems, that both shells in non-interactive no-login invocation doesn't read any start-up file like `/etc/profile`.

Is the default umask hard-wired in shell or it is inherited from cron daemon?

Comment: What's the problem with this? In a cron entry you can call any script or binary, and in a script you can source any other file you need to setup the environment.

Comment: @JennyD Thank you, move it please.
@ott Problem is that default umask is to open. Of course I know umask can be set in script or directly in crontab (`umask …`; script.sh). But I, as admin, want the default umask to be restrict and a release engineer can, for specific job, set an open umask. Not reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On RHEL, PAM is used, so you could try using `pam_umask`

Try putting this in `/etc/pam.d/crond`

```
session optional pam_umask.so umask=0022
```

Naturally, this is untested, and may very well break assumptions made by various applications.

Comment: Thank you. It is running for all crontabs (all users). I am afraid of side efects... How to set umask just for one crontab (one system user)?

Comment: I would have hoped you could do this in the crontab file itself (same as you can specify SHELL or MAILTO, or even MAILFROM or RANDOM_DELAY), but it appears not. pam_umask(8) does say you can put it in a user's GECOS information (and therefore into /etc/passwd or whereever you get that information from, such as LDAP -- bit yuck really). It might be better to set SHELL to pass arguments to call a particular init file.

Answer (score 2):

On >= RHEL7, it can be done by setting UMask value in systemd service

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Command Scheduler
After=auditd.service systemd-user-sessions.service time-sync.target

[Service]
UMask=0002
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/crond
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/crond -n $CRONDARGS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart crond.service
```